# Weighted Mean for multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, mean

I am trying to find the weighted mean per year (each row) over multiple columns.
However it just gives me one number for all 45 columns and all years...

I have tried this,

```
Weightedmean = Max_Year %>%
summarise(weighted.mean(Max_Year[,13:58], c(0.004961,0.005119,0.01368,0.01609,0.01623,0.005966,0.05848,
                                         0.01964, 0.01979,0.002283,0.003003,0.005639,0.02502,0.006511,
                                         0.005004,0.003045, 0.005926,0.004474,0.00746,0.004598,0.009667,
                                         0.002236,0.01318,0.002836,0.002751,0.002607,0.00745,0.00349,0.02161,
                                         0.002247,0.01697,0.005194,0.00678,0.01313,0.04428,0.004778,0.002424,
                                         0.0044,0.00365,0.08852,0.01103,0.005788,0.008653,0.02242,0.002705,0.007384))
```

```
but all i get is this
```

`weighted.mean(...)`

1                8736.

```
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `across`

```
Max_Year %>%
     mutate(wt = c(0.004961,0.005119,0.01368,0.01609,0.01623,0.005966,0.05848,
                                         0.01964, 0.01979,0.002283,0.003003,0.005639,0.02502,0.006511,
                                         0.005004,0.003045, 0.005926,0.004474,0.00746,0.004598,0.009667,
                                         0.002236,0.01318,0.002836,0.002751,0.002607,0.00745,0.00349,0.02161,
                                         0.002247,0.01697,0.005194,0.00678,0.01313,0.04428,0.004778,0.002424,
                                         0.0044,0.00365,0.08852,0.01103,0.005788,0.008653,0.02242,0.002705,0.007384)) %>%
     group_by(year) %>%
     summarise(across(13:58, ~ weighted.mean(., wt))
```